# How can getter/setter code be generated automatically for a class in Pharo or Squeak?

Tags: code-generation, smalltalk, getter-setter, pharo

I have a long list of instance variables to create for a class that I want to generate the code for, rather than do it by hand. The list comes from an existing SQL database. My intention is to do it all in a pure object-oriented way with Smalltalk first, and as I learn more, save the data back to the database and work from it directly.

Is there a way of passing the list of names to method that will generate them and add them to the class definition?

In fact is there a way of adding or modifying class definitions dynamically in Smalltalk? I suspect there must and I would like to know a best practices approach.

Update: What I have in mind is more like passing a list of the instance variables to a method that will create them automatically.

It is more like:

`addVariablesAndAccessors className: MyClass variablesList: ('aaaa', 'bbbb', 'cccc')`

which will then result in a call to

`AddVariables className: MyClass variableList: ('aaaa' 'bbbb' cccc')`

and

`generateAccessors className: MyClass variableList: ('aaaa' 'bbbb' cccc')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Squeak, you have `Behavior>>addInstVarName: aString`, so for instance, you could do something like:

```
String addInstVarName: 'foo'
```

Squeak also has refactoring support to generate accessors automatically. You can either use it directly or have a look at `AbstractInstanceVariableRefactoring>>createAccessors` to get some inspiration on how to implement your own ;-)

Another quite hacky but not so uncommon solution would be to just generate the instance variables, but instead of adding accessors, you overwrite `doesNotUnderstand:`, which gets called when an undefined selector is sent to your objects. There, you could check if you have an instance variable named according to the message, and return / change it if it is the case. Otherwise you just do `super doesNotUnderstand: aMessage`.

---

Regarding your comment: Classes are objects, too, so you don't have to do anything special to use them as parameters. On which class you add it is totally up to you and doesn't really matter. So a method to add instance variables could look like this:

```
addVariablesNamed: aCollection on: aClass

    aCollection do: [:each | aClass addInstVarName: each]
```

and you could call it like this:

```
yourObject addVariablesNamed: #('foo' 'bar' 'baz') on: ClassX
```

You can find examples on how to generate accessor methods in the class `CreateAccessorsForVariableRefactoring`

Comment: How would I do it from the top level so that I could make the class a parameter to the calling function ie. how do you define a method which takes a class as a parameter? What object is the method attached to?

Comment: I discovered the `Smalltalk at: #ClassName` approach but your method is more elegant.Regarding the class to attach the method to which one would be the most natural? How high up the hierarchy is it safe to go?

Comment: You could add it to `ClassDescription` itself, then you wouldn't even have to pass the class as parameter (because self is the class then). You could call `ClassX addVariablesNamed: aCollection` in this case

Answer (score 9):

In OmniBrowser with the refactoring tools loaded you select the class and in the context menu *Refactor class > Accessors*.

Alternatively, if you only want to create an accessor for a single variable, select *Refactor instance/class variable > Accessor*, and select the variable you want to access.

Answer (score 3):

In Squeak, open a `Browser` on the class. If you "right click" (I can never remember the button colours) the class name in the class list you'll get the standard context menu - "browse full (b)", and so on. Select "more..." and you'll see "create inst var accessors". Select that, and you'll get basic getters and setters for the instance variables.